# Get path of nested object in struct

Tags: ios, swift, codable, keypaths

I need to retrieve the path of a nested object.

Let's say I have a model that looks like this:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    struct ModelB: Codable {
        let props: [ModelC]
    }
    struct ModelC: Codable {
       let prop: Int
    }

    let modelB: ModelB
}
```

Then I have my instance:

```
let model = Model(modelB: Model.ModelB(props: [Model.ModelC(prop: 1),
                                               Model.ModelC(prop: 2),
                                               Model.ModelC(prop: 3)]))
```

Now I would like to to get the path of an element in `ModelB` `props`.
By doing something like:

```
print(model.modelB.props[0].path)
```

And the path I am expecting should look like:

> "modelB/props/0/modelC"

where `0` is the position of the element in the `props` array.

Is there anyway to achieve this either through the use of `CodingKey` or maybe `KeyPath`?

Comment: Do you want the print the entire path or do you just want a `keyPath` so you can use it?

Comment: The entire path

Comment: hm... then `KeyPath` won't help. It will only let you fetch the object but it doesn't show you it's components; Only it's `rootType` and `valueType`.

Comment: Plus... `CodingKey` is of no help whatsoever in this case

Comment: You might just have to create a `string` but then you can't make a `keyPath` out of it. That's afaik so I'll be watching this question for answers :) Best of luck